# How to modify a text in a textfile

Tags: visual-c++

I have a textfile that contains this line:

```
    C:\Program Files\app\
```

I want to read it to become this:

```
    C:\\Program Files\\app\\
```

I know how to read the file in visual c++, but how to add a slash() everytime it founds the slash.

```
    char str[200];
    fstream file_op("C:\\path.txt",ios::in);
    file_op >> str;
    file_op.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is through loop:

```
char newPath[MAX_PATH];
int newCount = 0;
for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{

    if(str[i] == '\')
    {
        newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
    }
    newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
}
```

Please note that you cannot change a file in place. You will have to write new strings to a new file. I am not using boost or any other library because those are not part of VisualC++ by default and your tag says you need this for VisualC++

Answer (score 2):

Using Boost:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  string line;
  ifstream file_op("D:\\path.txt");
  ofstream file_out("D:\\out.txt");
  while( getline(file_op, line) ) {
    boost::replace_all(line, "\\", "\\\\");
    file_out << line << '\n';
  }
  // file_op and file_out are closed on exit   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB you can use `String.Split()` to replace some chars with others, you might wanna try this or google for the use of "regex" (don't know the propper use either right now but I know that it was designed to replace and edit strings)

Comment: yeah and in VS you have all the nice .NET-Features you have in every language... like string-functions, regex, and so on... and even if it's not directly implemented you can find it googleing "regex c++" and the first link that comes is "http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184404797"... sorry if that sounds like trolling, but am I surrounded by complete idiots here!? had a simmilar discussion with some jerks at an other question...